# Optimising with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Currently, we're setting up dependencies inline on a html-page like this

```
<html>
    <body>

        <article>
            Content
        </article>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            define([
                'View',
                'Model'
            ], function(View, Model){
                new View({ model: Model });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Almost every page where we do this has different dependencies. We stayed away from creating main.js files because it'd mean that we would have a main.js file for every one of these pages.

**How would we best use the requirejs optimiser in our case?**

Comment: What are you referring in regards to 'main.js'?  The require.config setup or an application initializer?  I'm a bit confused since typically require is used to initialize an app in a single page's body and manage dependencies between views, models, and other scripts which will render HTML blocks back to the DOM.  Initializing require from multiple static HTML pages sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had much better success architecting my sites so that they share a common main.js. Or at least dividing the site into a small number sections that share builds. It takes some up-front planning, but it's a LOT easier to manage, and takes better advantage of the browser cache than one-build-per-page.

Comment: An example would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimize inline scripts with require.js. You should take a look at [htmlcompressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/).

Having several main.js files is not a problem with require.js whatever you use anonymous modules or not.

Olivier